# Socket io client error: SyntaxError: The requested module '@socket.io/component-emitter' is expected to be of type CommonJS

Tags: socket.io, next.js

I'm using nextjs, I install the package socket.io-client, and when trying to import, according to the docs:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module '@socket.io/component-emitter' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules 
can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from '@socket.io/component-emitter';
const { Emitter } = pkg;
```

The import is in index.js

Comment: What version of `socket.io-client` are you using?

Comment: I found out that the reason is an outdated Node version I was using! Thanks I'll update it here

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason is an outdated Node version I was using!